# Oracle DB error ORA-01003: No statement parsed

Tags: database, oracle

I'm working on Oracle DB and trying to increasethe tablespace using  resize command as below

```
alter database datafile '/SEL01/ora01/log_data06.dbf' resize 12G
```

The datafile size is 11G currently.I'm performing this action using HPOO tool.
Any suggestion why this error is coming up ?

Comment: if you want extra space with same datafile then you have to make this file extendible, or else you can add the other data with tablespace.

Comment: Adding other data table space is not an option in my case. The existing data group(/SEL01) has enough space to increase the data file size, but it is not happening